# Something like firebug for internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, bugs, firebug

Is there something like Firebug for Internet Explorer? I've got a site that is only supposed to be working in IE so I'm only targeting IE and the site is not supposed to work in Firefox.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<kbd>F12</kbd>. (Oh, that's too short for an answer). The <kbd>F12</kbd> key brings up built-in developer tools. It may not do everything that Firebug does, but it can do most things.

Comment: I just discovered this week that it has full Javascript debugging, which is great.

Comment: As a short addendum to this, the F12-tool has limited DOM manipulation but **very** good javascript debugging & profiling. You can also switch render engines to IE7/IE8 from there to get a general idea of how the older browsers will present your page. (Not a perfect representation, but catches 95% of the things)

Answer (score 8):

Your best options are [Firebug lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite), the newer [firebugger](http://www.firebugger.com/), or [IE Web Developer](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/ie-webdeveloper-firebug-for-internet-explorer/)

Answer (score 2):

The <kbd>F12</kbd>-tool does the most things needed.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome and FireFox have generally been the ones with the best expansion capability and built-in and third-party developer tools. However, IE9 has built-in developer tools allowing you to browse and step through client-side code in much the same way as Chrome's developer kit or FireBug. It's accessed, as paulmorriss said, using the F12 key or by opening the menu (the gear icon on the far right) and selecting "F12 developer tools".